# I am desperate to caulk over bad grout, for a short fix

Tags: shower, caulk

I keep reading "do not just caulk over bad grout", "do it the right way", "take out the grout is the only way to do it"... do it "right", yes. But I need to caulk it.

We havent used the shower in years, after learning it had not been properly renovated, with the intention of tearing the entire thing out ... but what if I am 35 weeks pregnant, on bed rest and am sick of my husband not getting on top of this one thing I wanted done before baby (to take a shower in my master bathroom). Why? Because my MIL will be staying with us and using the only other bathroom in the house and I dont want to share a bathroom with my MIL right after delivery.

Can I just caulk this kind of problem for a short while, somehow? A month maybe? The owners before us did a bad job on it and it is falling apart at the edges and corners. So we have not used it in years. Once I can get around after delivery - this reno project is getting DONE! In the meantime I want to be able to take a shower in my own room. Its a bathroom on 1st floor, with a cement floor. I dislike the entire thing. We want to just put in a fiberglass tub/shower but my husband has not given a lick about doing it before baby. And I am on bedrest. So, its been a sore situation as normally I am the one to initiate these projects. The whole house has been a project so it has just been frustrating.

Comment: Another option is to move, but I think my husband would miss me.

Comment: You can repeat the work as many times as you wish until you do it properly. Just pray that any water leaking past won't affect or damage the underlying materials.

Comment: Tell your MIL to pick up some grout and a float when she comes over. Explain to her that regrouting the shower will be an effective way for her to help out.

Comment: Since answers are blocked, I will suggest a possible short term solution in a comment.  Put up 5 mil or heavier poly on the walls, if that is where the leaking is.  That way you can use the shower while your MIL is there.  Unfortunate that everything is working against you. Enjoy the newborn!!